# How can a controller respond with an action to redirect from another website in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a newbie in ruby. I want to post a form data which includes an API key and some other field data to another website which will verify and send an http response 200 or 400 to my website. If I am able to connect to the api, the website responds with a URL redirect to my website with additional query string which my website will respond to. I don't how to do the following:

How to make my site respond to the redirect I get from the website through a controller and action. Assuming the controller is:

```
 class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def create
   Do something

   flash[:notice] = " book was created successfully"
  end

end
```

Configure my route to respond to the redirect

here is the code I am trying to use on view

```
   <form action="/master/master" method="POST" >
    <script
    src="https://js.example.co/v7/inline.js" 
    data-key= <%= ENV["EXAMPLE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
    data-email= <%= current_user.email %> 
    data-booktitle= <%= current_user.books.title %>
    data-ref= <% SecureRandom.random_number %> 
 >
  </script> 
  </form>
```

Comment: Its very unclear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to send a request server side from your controller to the external website and check if the response code is 200 or 400. Or are you trying to create a form that posts to another site which will then redirect the user back? Or are you trying to create an ajax request to the external website?

Comment: You have to be very clear where you want to post to and who will handle this. E.g. you can create a webpage which posts to another website, then you will have to handle the response in the browser (so javascript). If you want your own server to handle it, you have to first post the form-content to your own server (rails), which will then post it to the other server, and handle the response and then send a response back to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the basics of how to post a form to an external website. You'll have to fill in the details yourself since I have no clue what the external website does or what that script is supposed to accomplish.

Setting up a form to post to a remote url is pretty easy:

```
# Rails 4 and earlier
<% form_tag("http://example.com/test.php", method: :post) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :key, ENV["EXAMPLE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :title, current_user.books.title %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :ref, SecureRandom.random_number %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>

# Rails 5+
<%= form_with(url: "http://example.com/test.php", method: :post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :key, value: ENV["EXAMPLE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Handling the callback from the external website isn't really different then any other route in your rails app:

```
get '/some/path', to: 'foo#bar'
```

You just create a route that responds to GET, and configure whatever service that handles the form submission to redirect back to it.